# Update data in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I use jqGrid in this scenario:

1. The grid gets JSON data from the first URL. If the URL returns correct JSON - the grid displays that data.
2. If the URL returns incorrect data, then it fires the 'loadError' event of grid. In this event I want to change the URL of the grid to another URL and get the JSON data from the new URL.

Here is my code.

```
loadError: function(xhr, st, err) {
 $("#list").setGridParam({ url: '/new_url' });
        $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

But it doesnt't works. Why?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What happens when this code is executed?

Comment: is the loadError function actually getting called?

Comment: Yes, the body of loadError function executed.
I tried to call .trigger("reloadGrid") from another fuction - it works (new request sends to server). But if i call .trigger("reloadGrid") from loadError event - nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a really old question if someone else stumbles upon this try calling GridUnload first. So, your code would change to:

```
loadError: function(xhr, st, err) {
    $("#list").jqGrid('GridUnload');
    $("#list").setGridParam({ url: '/new_url' });
         $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```